# Cannot perform operation ".isEmpty" on org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.SubqueryExpression

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I have a subquery that looks like this: 
(It was rewrited from contains, because of perfomance issues)

**...(select  from RecoLock lock where mpiSubscriptionId == this.mpiSubscriptionId).isEmpty())**

And datanucleus throws me a

---

**Cannot perform operation ".isEmpty" on org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.SubqueryExpression**

---

But in datanucleus [documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/query.html) there are examples where similiar code workds well. What am I doing wrong?

datanucleus version is 4.1.0

Comment: Judging by the javadoc, there's no `isEmpty()` method in the SubqueryExpression class. What is the exemple you're using?

Comment: @AlexFerretti here http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/query.html in "Using methods on the subquery" is an example

Comment: Check your imports. Check if thats the right `isEmpty()`.

Comment: You refer to documentation for DataNucleus v5.0, yet say you are using 4.1.0. Perhaps that is the reason ? There is documentation for all versions, and that documentation I think always refers to the latest on that branch. Since you are using 4.1.0, you are no where near the latest release on that branch even, never mind on 5.0

Comment: @Neil Stockton good point, thank you, I will try to update it

Comment: kindly ACCEPT the provided answer if it works for you, and if not then SAY what doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see of the DataNucleus JDOQL support for `{subquery}.isEmpty()` this is only supported from v5.0.

If using v4.x (or earlier) you can transform your query to do

```
... (select COUNT(lock) from RecoLock lock where mpiSubscriptionId == this.mpiSubscriptionId) == 0)
```

which should equate to the same thing as "size == 0" (i.e "empty")